# Which is more efficient fgetc vs fread?

Tags: c, assembly, dos, x86-16

I want to copy the contents of one file to the other.

Initially I thought that `fgetc()` would be better than `fread()` as the program won't need to reiterate through the buffer just to copy each character.

But I soon realize that repeatedly using `fgetc()` is equivalent of doing multiple function calls (stack pointer) so that way it will make the process more time consuming in case of large files.

Which is more efficient?

`size_t _Cdecl fread(void *__ptr, size_t __size, size_t __n,
                     FILE *__stream);`

vs

`int _Cdecl fgetc(FILE *__stream);`

Comment: They do completely different things, it doesn't make sense to compare them.

Comment: Even after you use `setbuf()` you still have to use `fgetc()` to read from the file. `setbuf()` just allows you to supply your own buffer instead of the internal buffer used by stdio.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is copying one file to another, then skipping the standard I/O library and going to direct operating system calls with a good-sized buffer is probably going to be more efficient.  Open file `open()` on Linux or `CreateFile` on Windows, then go into a read/write loop around a common buffer.

Comment: I believe you might have misunderstood what `setbuf` does.  Perhaps you want `fread` instead?

Comment: Oh wait..I'm sorry..Let me correct it.

Comment: On old systems `fgetc` was actually often faster than `fread`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with *`fgetc`* is that modern C implementations support *threads*. A `FILE` can be shared by several threads and that is why accesses to the buffer will need explicit locking. While you can enlarge the buffer by using `setbuf`, it does not eliminate the need for locking. Therefore a `fread` call will be almost always more performant than multiple `fgetc` calls.

Any `setbuf` setting can only do so much to performance. To read a single character at a time from a buffered stream you can use the POSIX standard `flockfile`/`funlockfile` and `getc_unlocked` when the file is locked for your thread.

But even then, `fread` is very likely more performant than multiple `getc_unlocked` calls, because it has been optimized to read a *block*.

Comment: Is there any way to synchronously do it?

Comment: I mean without using a buffer

Comment: those functions are already synchronous... you don't get much faster than stdio, buffering is essential to speed

Comment: Synchronous as in a function to directly copy each character to the other file instead of copying it to another buffer.

Comment: On Linux there's `sendfile()` that directly copies one file to another.  Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile

Comment: and there is also `splice` that works for any descriptors.

Comment: In general/perhaps for Windows+DOS?

Comment: DOS? If someone cares about efficiency they would not be using DOS.

Comment: I'm creating a common code for both DOS and Windows

Comment: Is there some way to get the contents of a file directly? I mean as in without copy each character in another buffer?

Comment: @HelloWorld You do know that people use buffers because it's faster to read a bunch of characters at once into a buffer than to read each character individually, even if it involves an extra copy?

Comment: Is there any way to get a pointer which contains the contents of the file that's terminated by a 0? (dynamic)

Comment: @HelloWorld That's basically what `fread` does: it reads data from the file into a buffer so you can process the data.  As for your second question: no, there is not.  This is generally not a good idea as the file might be too big to fit into main storage.  However, you can get a similar effect using memory-mapped IO.  It's not necessarily faster than using `fread` though.

Comment: Is there any way to get a dynamic buffer? I mean without explicitly giving it the size? Something `char* getcontents(FILE *file)`

Comment: Is there any way to get a dynamic buffer?

Comment: @HelloWorld yes, memory mapped IO, but not in DOS. **Nothing** works in DOS.

Comment: @HelloWorld Please refrain from posting multiple comments for the same question.  Well, you can find the size of the file, then allocate an appropriately sized buffer and then read the entire file into it with `fread`, but this approach is prone to race conditions.  The best way is to process the file by reading and processing it piece by piece with `fread`.

Comment: @fuz Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to frequently ask questions. Else I would you to do it that way,

Comment: @HelloWorld That is a feature.  Try to find solutions on your own first before asking tons of questions.  Also, with your level of knowledge, it might be a good idea to work through a book on programming in C first as you seem to have some weird preconceptions about how things work.

Comment: It is quite unfortunate that the historical solution to threading was "put a lock on everything".